# Propositions as sets of witnesses

Tags: reference-request, logic, foundations

Under the propositions-as-types paradigms, a proposition is identified with the type of all its proofs. From a more classical perspective (and assuming the full-blown axiom of choice), it sometimes makes sense to think of propositions as representing not mere truthvalues, but rather, sets of witnesses. We can then define that a proposition is *true* iff it represents a non-empty set.

For example, a proposition of the form

$$\exists x \in X.P(x)$$

could be identified with the set of all $x \in X$ such that $P(x).$ Along a similar vein, a proposition of the form

$$\forall x \in X, \exists y \in Y . P(x,y)$$

could be identified with the set of all functions $y:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $P(x,y(x))$ holds for all $x \in X$.

More generally, to work out what set is represented by a proposition, we can:

1. Convert to [prenex normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form).
2. Shuffle all the existential quantifiers left across the universal quantifiers. For example, a formula of the form $(\forall x \in X)(\exists y \in Y)(\varphi)$ would be transformed into a formula of the form $(\exists y : X \rightarrow Y)(\forall x \in X)([y(x)/x]\varphi)$. Do this until all the existential quantifiers are at the left-most position. Compare with [Skolem normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form).
3. Replace the existential quantifiers with set abstraction. e.g. $(\exists x \in X)(\forall y \in Y)(\varphi)$ would become $\{x \in X \mid (\forall y \in Y)(\varphi)\}.$

**Caveat.** I'm not sure this actually makes sense. In particular, if there are many different ways of transforming a formula into prenex normal form, then perhaps these correspond to different sets.

> **Question 0.** Does this suggestion fall prey to the aforementioned caveat? If so, I'd like to see an explicit example of the problem.
>
> **Question 1.** Have any authors suggested anything like this? If so, I'd appreciate a link or reference.

Comment: Quine may have in his _Methods of Logic_. I'd suggest to look through the second half of Part II and the first half of Part I, if you have time. Haven't read it in a while, so I can't say which chapters specifically, but there are some obvious ones on prenexity and purity and so on.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan, thanks, I'll check it out.